# Support design v.23.1.0 and v.23.1.1 broke menu in NavigationView

Tags: android, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport, android-navigationview

New versions of Support design (23.1.0 and 23.1.1) broke menu in NavigationView 
Normal menu 
[image]

Menu in new api version

[image]

Menu xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="none">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
        android:title="@string/navigation_list_log_out" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
        android:title="@string/navigation_list_log_out" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
        android:title="@string/navigation_list_log_out" />
</group>
```

So last right version is

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

Maybe Google know how to fast fix this bug in new version?

Comment: does your texviews and icons have colors/tint? can you still select them? (even if not visible)

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla i can select, but text is not visible. So i tried to set text and background color in xml and programmatically but unsuccessfully.

Comment: what about the adapter? everything fine there? weird. EDIT: Did you try to come back to 23.0.1? If 23.1.1 crash that... may be a Google issue/bug for sure.

Comment: Comeback to 23.0.1 work correct. So it's Google bug :)

Comment: Yep... :-/ let's wait for a 23.1.2 then!

Comment: I agree with you comrade!

Comment: Could you post your menu xml too?

Comment: Is it really missing the closing `</menu>`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it looks like version 23.1.0 - 23.1.1 of the support library broke the behaviour of the `android:checkableBehaviour` attribute, as well as the `menuItem.setChecked(boolean)` method.

You may want to keep an eye on this [AOSP Issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194520), which details the reason why these behaviours are broken.

Try calling something like `mNavView.setItemTextColor(mNavView.getItemTextColor)` as a workaround, as recommended in that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please change none to single.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
        android:title="@string/navigation_list_log_out" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
        android:title="@string/navigation_list_log_out" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
        android:title="@string/navigation_list_log_out" />
</group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 'com.android.support:design:**23.0.1**' to 'com.android.support:design:**23.1.1**'then sync the project. The version actually works.